# Conditionally replace missing values depending on surrounding non-missing values

Tags: r, vectorization, na, missing-data

I am trying to replace missing values (`NA`) in a vector. `NA` between two equal number is replaced by that number. `NA` between two different values, should stay `NA`. For example, given vector "a", I want it to be "b".

```
a = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 3)
b = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

As you can see, the second run of `NA`, between the values `1` and `2`, is not replaced.

Is there a way to vectorize the calculation?

Comment: If there are `NA` at the beginning or end of the vector, do they stay `NA`?

Comment: Yes. they stay NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use convenience functions from `zoo` package. Here we replace `NA` in the original vector where interpolated values (create by `na.approx`) equals the 'last observations carried forward' (created by `na.locf`):

```
library(zoo)
a_ap <- na.approx(a)
a_locf <- na.locf(a)
a[which(a_ap == a_locf)] <- a_ap[which(a_ap == a_locf)]
a
# [1]  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3
```

To account for leading and trailing `NA`, add `na.rm = FALSE`:

```
a <- c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA)

a_ap <- na.approx(a, na.rm = FALSE)
a_locf <- na.locf(a, na.rm = FALSE)
a[which(a_ap == a_locf)] <- a_ap[which(a_ap == a_locf)]
a
# [1] NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

OP asked for a *vecgorized* solution, so here's a possible vectorized base R solution (without for loops) that also handles situations with leading/lagging NAs

```
# Define a vector with Leading/Lagging NAs
a <- c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA)

# Save the boolean vector as we are going to reuse it a lot
na_vals <- is.na(a)

# Find the NAs location compared to the non-NAs
ind <- findInterval(which(na_vals), which(!na_vals))

# Find the consecutive values that equal
ind2 <- which(!diff(a[!na_vals]))

# Fill only NAs between equal consequtive files
a[na_vals] <- a[!na_vals][ind2[match(ind, ind2)]]
a
# [1] NA NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3 NA NA
```

---

**Some time comparisons for big vectors**

```
# Create a big vector
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(c(NA, 1:5), 5e7, replace = TRUE)

############################################
##### Cainã Max Couto-Silva

fill_data <- function(vec) {

  for(l in unique(vec[!is.na(vec)])) {

    g <- which(vec %in% l)

    indexes <- list()

    for(i in 1:(length(g) - 1)) {
      indexes[[i]] <- (g[i]+1):(g[i+1]-1)
    }

    for(i in 1:(length(g) - 1)) { 
      if(all(is.na(vec[indexes[[i]]]))) {
        vec[indexes[[i]]] <- l
      }
    }
  }

  return(vec)
}

system.time(res <- fill_data(a))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  81.73    4.41   86.48 

############################################
##### Henrik

system.time({
  a_ap <- na.approx(a, na.rm = FALSE)
  a_locf <- na.locf(a, na.rm = FALSE)
  a[which(a_ap == a_locf)] <- a_ap[which(a_ap == a_locf)]
})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 12.55    3.39   15.98 

# Validate
identical(res, as.integer(a))
# [1] TRUE

############################################
##### David

## Recreate a as it been overridden
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(c(NA, 1:5), 5e7, replace = TRUE)

system.time({
  # Save the boolean vector as we are going to reuse it a lot
  na_vals <- is.na(a)

  # Find the NAs location compaed to the non-NAs
  ind <- findInterval(which(na_vals), which(!na_vals))

  # Find the consecutive values that equl
  ind2 <- which(!diff(a[!na_vals]))

  # Fill only NAs between equal consequtive files
  a[na_vals] <- a[!na_vals][ind2[match(ind, ind2)]]
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.39    0.71    4.13 

# Validate
identical(res, a)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can make a function like that:**

```
fill_data <- function(vec) {

  for(l in unique(vec[!is.na(vec)])) {

    g <- which(vec %in% l)

    indexes <- list()

    for(i in 1:(length(g) - 1)) {
      indexes[[i]] <- (g[i]+1):(g[i+1]-1)
    }

    for(i in 1:(length(g) - 1)) { 
      if(all(is.na(vec[indexes[[i]]]))) {
        vec[indexes[[i]]] <- l
      }
    }
  }

  return(vec)
}
```

**Running function:**

```
a = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 3)

fill_data(a)
[1]  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3
```

If you have a vector with values in different places it also works:

```
ab = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA , 1, NA, 1, 3, NA, NA, 3)

fill_data(ab)
[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA  2  2  2  2  2 NA  1  1  1  3  3  3  3
```

---

**Explanation:**

First, you find the unique non-NA values.

Then it takes the indexes of each unique non-NA value and acquires the values between them;

Then it tests if these values are all NAs and, if they are, replace them by the level's value.

Comment: Technically doesn't fit OP's requirements, since output is a character vector no matter what. If you add `vec_cls <- class(vec)` at the very beginning of the function and `class(vec) <- vec_cls` just before the return that would fix it. Or even better would be to use `unique(vec[!is.na(vec)])` instead of `levels(factor(vec))` and then `g <- which(vec %in% l)` instead of `grep`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the character vector returned, but I think it would not be a problem at all since it would be easily fixed afterwards by `res <- as.cls(res)`. Surely is more practical to fix that inside the function. Feel free for editing the answer (it's my first answer here). Kind regards.

Comment: I like the edit that avoids the whole problem by not going to levels and grep. Would be more efficient probably too.

Comment: This very un-vectorized, while OP asked explicitly for a vectorized solution